# Multiple unary operators in an if statement

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax, unary-operator

Is it possible to have multiple unary operators in if statements.. Here is the code snippet which is giving me error.

Please correct the code here.

```
if [ -f $input_file ] -a [ -f $output_file ] -a [ -f $log_file ] ]
then
    ### Some Code here
fi
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if [ -f "file1" -a -f "file2" -a "file3" ]; then
   #some code
fi
```

Comment: It works like a Magic.. 
thanks for the quick response..

Answer (score 8):

If you use Bash's double-bracket, you can do this:

```
if [[ -f "$input_file" && -f "$output_file" && -f "$log_file" ]]
```

which I find cleaner to read than other options shown here (but that's subjective). However, it has [other advantages](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031).

And, as **ghostdog74** shows, you should always quote variables containing filenames.

Comment: It's not necessary to quote variables containing filenames if you use double-bracket because BASH doesn't do WordSplitting with double-brackets.  See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

Answer (score 5):

You can see the  `[ ... ]` operator only as a shortcut for `test ...`. The options are used th same way.

So in your case you could either write the *ghostdog74* way or :

```
if [ -f $input_file ] && [ -f $output_file ] && [ -f $log_file ]
then
### Some Code here
fi
```

Comment: It's important to put variables inside double quotes inside `[ ... ]` to prevent mishaps arising out of word splitting as well as the possibility of variables evaluating to nothing.  However, double quotes are optional inside the Bash-specific `[[ ... ]]`.

Answer (score 1):

`[` is a command, not part of the `if` statement. As such you should pass it each of the appropriate arguments instead of trying to incorrectly run it as you have.

```
if [ arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 ... ]
then
```

Comment: In Cygwin environments, there is a C:\cygwin\bin\\[.exe. Really strange feeling to take a look at this folder for the first time.

Comment: Similar command `[` in `/usr/bin` on most linux distros, despite which `[` is usually a bash builtin.