# check two conditions in if statement in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have problem in writing if statement

```
var1=`COMMAND | grep <Something>`
if [ -n "$var1" ] && if [[ "$var1" != string ]]; then
    .
    .
    .
fi
```

I want to write if statement that check:

If **var1** is not null **AND** if string(could be `hello` word) is not in var1 then do stuff.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use something like this:

```
if [ -n "$var1" ] && [[ ! $var1 == *string* ]]; then
...
fi
```

See an example:

```
$ v="hello"
$ if [ -n "$v" ] && [[ $v == *el* ]] ; then echo "yes"; fi
yes
$ if [ -n "$v" ] && [[ ! $v == *ba* ]] ; then echo "yes"; fi
yes
```

The second condition is a variation of what is indicated in [String contains in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/229551/1983854).

Comment: Can I use `[[ $v != *el* ]]`  ?

Comment: Ops, updated. You need `[[ ! $var == *string* ]]`. That is, negate the condition.

Comment: There's also `! [[ $var1 == *string* ]]` and `[[ $var1 != *string* ]]`. Options abound :)

Answer (score 4):

Other possibilities:

```
if [ -n "$var1" -a "$var1" != string ]; then ...

if [ "${var1:-xxx}" != "string" ]; then ...
```

Comment: Thank you... I was searching aboat `-a` and `-o` in if statements as well

Comment: You can ignore `-a` and `-o` as Boolean operators. Even the POSIX standard recommends using `[ ... ] && [ ... ]` in place of `[ ... -a ...]` (and similarly for `||` in place of `-o`).

Comment: @chepner Interesting. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @chepner Thank you..So it is better to use `&&` and `||` rather than `-a` and `-o`...

Comment: @MortezaLSC yes, see [this good explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396146/using-and-operator-in-if-statement-bash-script#comment23507000_16396181): "Note that POSIX recommends the use of `&&` and `||` with the single bracket notation over `-a` and `-o`".

Answer (score 1):

You should rephrase the condition like this:

```
var1=`COMMAND | grep <Something>`
if [ -n "$var1" ] && [[ "$var1" != "string" ]]; then
.
.
.
fi
```

or the equivalent:

```
if test -n "$var1"  && test "$var1" != "string"
then
...
fi
```

Comment: Ohhh..  I thought  I can't use [] format with string//// Thank you.. let me check