# How to include three "AND" conditions in bash script

Tags: bash

Im trying to create three test conditions so that diretory and user and group account permisions are set on a directory - when I use the script below with -a to include the and conditions they are not picked up - If I do them individually they work - where am I going wrong ?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $(stat -c "%a" /wwwserver/virtual_hosts/www.test1.com) != "750"  -a  $(stat -c "%U" /wwwserver/virtual_hosts/www.test1.com) != "user"  -a  $(stat -c "%G" /wwwserver/virtual_hosts/www.test1.com) != "group" ] ;
 then echo -e "\n\nDirectory Permissions Changed\n" $(stat /wwwserver/virtual_hosts/www.test1.com) "\n" "\nChanging Permissions back to 750 user group\n" | mail -s " Directory Permissions Changed for www.test1.com" mail@test1.com;
        chmod 750 /wwwserver/virtual_hosts/www.test1.com;
        chown -R user.group /wwwserver/virtual_hosts/www.test1.com;
fi
```

Comment: @fedorqui I'm not sure if the close vote really applies here...

Comment: @hek2mgl Well I had the feeling that the problem was in the way the `and` operators are placed, since every single one works to the OP. So I addressed to that question in which [I] tried to indicate what is the correct way of adding more than one conditions in a Bash `if`. But if you believe it is not an appropiate duplicate, I can reopen it of course. Let me know.

Comment: Basically it is a *non problem* (I proved that in my answer).. Probably the best would be if the OP deletes the question after realizing that.. I just wanted to avoid that people who enter this site from google may think a triple `and` condition is possible only using the extended `if`. It is indeed possible with the simple (POSIX) `if` as well.

Comment: @fedorqui You probably may reopen it? ... :)

Comment: @hek2mgl sure, done! For the record, the question I had linked is [using and (&&) operator in if statement bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16396146/1983854).

Comment: @fedorqui Now, having two ups and the accept I think it appears more `on-topic` than before .. hehe..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically your scripts works, check:

```
touch "test1.com"
chmod 400 "test1.com"

if [ $(stat -c "%a" "test1.com") != "750" -a $(stat -c "%U" "test1.com") != "user" -a $(stat -c "%G" "test1.com") != "group" ]
then
    echo "do something ..."
fi
```

This outputs `do something ...`.

It looks like one of the 3 conditions do indeed fail in your case. Meaning either file permissions are already `750` or ownership is already set to `user` or group ownership is set to `group`.

---

Btw, I strongly recommend to quote the command substitutions properly. This is because the output returned from that commands may contain problematic characters which would get interpreted by the shell otherwise. Care about quoting in any situation during shell scripting, regardless what output you may expect -> pigs can fly!

Here comes the example above - properly quoted:

```
touch "test1.com"
chmod 400 "test1.com"

if [ "$(stat -c "%a" "test1.com")" != "750" -a "$(stat -c "%U" "test1.com")" != "user" -a "$(stat -c "%G" "test1.com")" != "group" ]
then
    echo "do something ..."
fi
```

Comment: No harm in advocating some double quotes around the command substitutions as well.

Comment: Thanks hek2mgl - I got the logic wrong in my head - thanks for pointing that out for me - working fine now

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple anded conditions like this:

```
s='abc'
n=4
m=5

[[ -n "$s" && $n > 3 && $m > 6 ]] && echo "all conditions passed"
all conditions passed
```

I.e. use `[[...]]` for all conditions and use `&&` for anding.