# Shell conditional expressions - differences between (-o vs ||) and (-a vs &&)

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, conditional-statements

Context : I was looking for short-circuiting behavior of logical Or, and the below seems to be working (I'm using zsh).

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ] || [ ! -d $1 ]; then
```

But in my search, I came across examples using each of the above Or's and And's. So what's the difference between them in terms of:

- short-circuiting
- shell specificity (like bash vs zsh)
- any other relevant aspects

EDIT : Also, found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28781/what-is-the-syntax-of-a-complex-condition-in-shell) very useful.

Comment: See in [using and (&&) operator in if statement bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396146/using-and-operator-in-if-statement-bash-script/16396181#comment23507000_16396181) the comment by Adrian Frühwirth: _Note that [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/test.html#tag_04_140_16) recommends the use of && and || with the single bracket notation over -a and -o._

Comment: The posted example is indeed a short-circuiting command that is also POSIX-compliant (although you should quote `$1` to guard against an empty value). Beyond that, the question itself is too broad to be answered usefully.

Comment: updated the question. Found out that 'AND' and 'OR' were not actually being used as keywords. Thanks