# KSH scripting: -z and -a

Tags: linux, ksh

I have the below condition:

```
 if [ ! -z $DateC -a "$DateC"=="$DateJ" ]
```

If had like to know what -z and -a means.  I don't understand what this condition verifies.  I have searched the net for -a and -z but I don't really get what it does.  Any help, pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `man test` for this:

```
   -z STRING
          the length of STRING is zero
   EXPRESSION1 -a EXPRESSION2
          both EXPRESSION1 and EXPRESSION2 are true
```

So this checks if the length of `$DateC` is not zero and `$DateC` and `$DateJ` are equal.

```bash
if [ ! -z $DateC -a "$DateC"=="$DateJ" ] 
#      ^^^^^^^^^ ^^
#         |     AND
#         |
#      length of string is zero
#
#    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#    length of string is NOT zero
```

See an example:

```bash
$ r=hello
$ s=hello
$ [ "$r"=="$s" ] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes
```

With the other condition:

```bash
$ t=""
$ if [ ! -z "$t" -a "$r"=="$s" ]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi
no
$ t=a
$ if [ ! -z "$t" -a "$r"=="$s" ]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi
yes
```

Finally,

> Note that [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/test.html#tag_04_140_16) recommends the use of `&&` and `||` with the
>   single bracket notation over `-a` and `-o`, so if you are writing
>   portable code go for the first notation, otherwise the second and skip
>   the third, especially since it can get awkward and hard to read if you
>   need to group expressions. – [Adrian Frühwirth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/612462/adrian-fr%C3%BChwirth) ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396146/using-and-operator-in-if-statement-bash-script/16396181#comment23507000_16396181))