# Running script conditionally does not work in travis.yml, why?

Tags: bash, yaml, travis-ci

The following causes travis to not build at all. When I try to validate the `travis.yml` file, it complains that the line just above the if statement is missing a `-` character at column 3, but the error has to do with the if statement below.

Do I have to move the if statement out to a script?

```
# Deploy
after_success:
  - ./tools/docker-push-container.sh
  - if [ $TRAVIS_BRANCH == "master" && $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST == "false" ]; then
      ./.travis/success_message.sh
    fi
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You're making some assumptions about YAML syntax that are causing you problems.  If you "exend" a line of YAML by indenting subsequent lines, like this:

```
- The quick brown fox
  jumped over the
  lazy dog.
```

It is exactly like you instead wrote this:

```
- The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
```

This means that your shell fragment, which you've written as:

```
  - if [ $TRAVIS_BRANCH == "master" && $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST == "false" ]; then
      ./.travis/success_message.sh
    fi
```

Actually becomes:

```
if [ $TRAVIS_BRANCH == "master" && $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST == "false" ]; then ./.travis/success_message.sh fi
```

And if you try run that line in the shell, you get:

```
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

If you want to include a multi-line shell script in your YAML document, your best bet is probably to use the verbatim block operator, `|`, like this:

```
  - |
    if [ $TRAVIS_BRANCH == "master" && $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST == "false" ]; then
      ./.travis/success_message.sh
    fi
```

Which will result, as intended, in:

```
if [ $TRAVIS_BRANCH == "master" && $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST == "false" ]; then
  ./.travis/success_message.sh
fi
```

Alternatively, you could just make proper use of semicolons:

```
  - if [ $TRAVIS_BRANCH == "master" && $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST == "false" ]; then
      ./.travis/success_message.sh;
    fi
```

Note the new `;` before the terminal `fi`.  This results in:

```
if [ $TRAVIS_BRANCH == "master" && $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST == "false" ]; then ./.travis/success_message.sh; fi
```

...which is perfectly valid shell syntax.

Answer (score 4):

I tried the above solution by **larsks** but, it did not work for me and could be because in `bash` when you use `&&` and `||` you need to separate the conditions.

I had the following (according to above solution)

```
  - if [ $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST == false && $TRAVIS_BRANCH == "development" ]; then
        echo "# Bump version and flyway migrate db"; 
    else 
        echo "Skip version increment!"; 
    fi
```

And I also checked the `.travis.yml` in [Travis Lint](http://lint.travis-ci.org/) and it shows as valid but, according to bash the above can be separated as shown below, also mentioned in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396146/using-and-operator-in-if-statement-bash-script) and I changed to following

```
    - if [ $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST == false ] && [ $TRAVIS_BRANCH == "development" ]; then
            echo "# Bump version and flyway migrate db"; 
        else 
            echo "Skip version increment!"; 
        fi
```

And *travis build* worked. It kind of make sense because above is valid way to use **&&** and **||** in bash. Just sharing in case someone else come across a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Raf's solution worked for me with separating the conditionals with []

```
[ $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST == false ] && [ $TRAVIS_BRANCH == "develop" ];
```

Comment: It's worked plenty. I have a lot of them over multiple projects now.

Answer (score 0):

None of the suggested workarounds worked for me, I used this instead:

```
- if [[ ( "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "osx" ) && ( "$TOXENV" == "py36" ) ]]; then brew update; fi
```