# if [ $inst != "GPS" && $inst != "USRP" ] results in error: missing `]'

Tags: bash, shell

```
if [ $inst != "GPS" && $inst != "USRP" && $inst != "GCSM" &&  $inst != "EFMS" && $inst != "instAR" && $inst != "CRF" && $inst != "DBOR" && $inst != "PAL"     &&  $inst != "GRDB" && $inst != "GIOM" && $inst != "FA" && $inst != "WS" ]
then
    help
fi
```

Error message:

```
30: [: missing `]'
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: You could change `&&` to `-a` but it has its own pitfall like `[ -z "$var" -o "$var" -eq 0 ]`, so it is not recommended.

Comment: You added the `bash` tag but you didn't read it. Run your code through `shellcheck` as it instructs.

Comment: `-a` is even worse than `-o`, since it's also a unary operator.

Answer (score 2):

Bash's error messages can be cryptic. Why does it say there's a missing `]` when you have one at the end of the line? I don't blame you for finding that confusing.

[Shell Check](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is a great tool for linting shell scripts, often producing much better diagnostics with links to detailed writeups. For your script it reports:

> SC2107 (error): Instead of `[ a && b ]`, use `[ a ] && [ b ]`.

The [full explanation for SC2107](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2107) reads:

> ### Instead of `[ a && b ]`, use `[ a ] && [ b ]`.
>
> #### Problematic code:
>
> ```sh
> [ "$1" = "-v" && -z "$2" ]
> ```
>
> #### Correct code:
>
> ```sh
> [ "$1" = "-v" ] && [ -z "$2" ]
> ```
>
> #### Rationale:
>
> `&&` can not be used in a `[ .. ]` test expression. Instead, make two `[ .. ]` expressions and put the `&&` between them.
>
> #### Exceptions:
>
> None.
>
> #### Related resources:
>
> - [Bash Pitfalls: [ "$foo" = bar && "$bar" = foo ]](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf6)
> - [StackOverflow: using and (&&) operator in if statement bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396146/using-and-operator-in-if-statement-bash-script/16396181)

---

An alternative way to write the check is to use a `case` block.

```
case "$inst" in
    GPS|USRP|GCSM|EFMS|instAR|CRF|DBOR|PAL|GRDB|GIOM|FA|WS)
        # match
        ;;

    *)
        # no match
        help
        ;;
esac
```

Or you could use `=~` to match against a regular expression. Note that this requires the use of double square brackets `[[` as well, and therefore requires a `#!/bin/bash` shebang. It won't work in a plain `#!/bin/sh` script.

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! [[ $inst =~ ^(GPS|USRP|GCSM|EFMS|instAR|CRF|DBOR|PAL|GRDB|GIOM|FA|WS)$ ]]
    help
fi
```

Comment: I thought SO encouraged, nay demanded, some effort on the part of the poster.

Comment: @Roadowl OP wrote some code and didn't understand why it was wrong. That's a far cry from providing a description of the program to write with no code whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are trying to use is quite unwieldy anyway. May I suggest you switch to a `case` statement instead?

```
case $inst in 
  GPS|USRP|GCSM|EFMS|instAR|CRF|DBOR|PAL|GRDB|GIOM|FA|WS)
    ;;
  *)
    help
  ;;
esac
```

The punctuation-heavy syntax of this statement may be jarring at first, but you should find that it is a lot more robust and versatile than the clunky `if`.

Comment: @triplee don't you need to be using `[[...]]` instead of `[...]` to be able to use `&&` instead of `-a`? I don;t really remember right now and am too lazy to look it up or try it.

Comment: It's not a shell syntax error, it's a `test`/`[` error. The `&&` separates the simple command `[ $inst != "GPS"` from another command list, and `[` is noting that it did not receive its mandatory final argument `]`.